# Conditional frequency of elements within lists in pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, frequency

I have a data frame in pandas like this:

```
STATUS      FEATURES
  A          [x,y,z]
  A          [t, y]
  B          [x,p,t]
  B           [x,p]
```

I want to count the frequency of the elements in the lists of features conditional on the status.
The desired output would be:

```
STATUS       FEATURES      FREQUENCY
  A             x              1
  A             y              2
  A             z              1
  A             t              1
  B             x              2
  B             t              1
  B             p              2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us do `explode` , the `groupby` `size`

```
s=df.explode(['FEATURES']).groupby(['STATUS','FEATURES']).size().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
new_df = (df.explode('FEATURES')
            .groupby('STATUS')['FEATURES']
            .value_counts()
            .reset_index(name='FRECUENCY'))
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
  STATUS FEATURES  FRECUENCY
0      A        y          2
1      A        t          1
2      A        x          1
3      A        z          1
4      B        p          2
5      B        x          2
6      B        t          1
```